# MacMail rules don't work for follow up messages

Tags: applescript, email

I am trying to archive emails where the last message contains a keyword.

I am not able to do this with Rules in MacMail as it seems it only cares about the first message in the inbox. How can archive the whole thread of messages (the entire "conversation") as soon as the last message sent or received contains such word?

This is what I did but doesn't work:

[image]

Comment: Could you include the actions that should be performed by the rule in the screenshot?